# Object.assign nested array with only certain properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have json data from below. The goal is to take all the Orders and combine them into one array while maintaining the Amount and the `IdNumber` so that I can use lodash `_.groupBy` on the Type.

In the end I'll have, for example, Type: test with each IdNumber and the Order Amounts that correspond to that IdNumber

I tried `Object.assign` on the data and did

```
data.forEach(d => {
    let orders = d['Orders'];    
    let newOrders = Object.assign({}, {Idnumber: data.IdNumber, Orders: orders});
    let groupedOrders = _.groupBy(newOrders, 'Type');
});
```

But, I'm not sure how to get just the Amount and Type of orders and merge them into one array. I'm also unclear if Object.assign is keeping track of the IdNumber with the Orders. when going through the array. I've never used Object.assign so perhaps that isn't even the right method to go about what I need.

Json data:

```
data = [
    {
        "Name": "abc",
        "Amount": 3000,
        "Idnumber": "001",
        "Date": "11/17/2017",
        "Orders": [
            {
                "Order Number": "11",
                "Date": "11/18/2017",
                "Amount": 1000,
                "Type": "test"
            },
            {
                "Order Number": "12",
                "Date": "12/31/2017",
                "Amount": 2000,
                "Type": "trial"
            }
        ],
        "foo": "foo",
        "foo2": foo,
        "foo3": "foo",
        "foo4": "foo"
    },
    {
        "Name": "def",
        "Amount": 5000,
        "Idnumber": "002",
        "Date": "12/15/2017",
        "Orders": [
            {
                "Order Number": "10",
                "Date": "11/02/2017",
                "Amount": 7600,
                "Type": "trial"
            },
            {
                "Order Number": "16",
                "Date": "05/31/2018",
                "Amount": 15000,
                "Type": "interim"
            }
        ],
        "foo": "foo",
        "foo2": foo,
        "foo3": "foo",
        "foo4": "foo"
    }
]
```

Comment: `Object.assign({}, {Idnumber: data.IdNumber, Orders: orders})` is pointless. This expression has exactly the same effect as just writing `{Idnumber: data.IdNumber, Orders: orders}`.

Comment: That's the gist I'm getting now that I've played around with it. Perhaps I need to do a flatten or reduce.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I want to be able to group the Orders by the Type, but need to maintain the Idnumber with the Amount so that I can match the IdNumber to another database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` and `array#map` to inject `Idnumber` to each order and later on use `array#reduce` to group data based on the `Type`.

```js
const data = [{"Name":"abc","Amount":3000,"Idnumber":"001","Date":"11/17/2017","Orders":[{"Order Number":"11","Date":"11/18/2017","Amount":1000,"Type":"test"},{"Order Number":"12","Date":"12/31/2017","Amount":2000,"Type":"trial"}],"foo":"foo","foo2":"foo","foo3":"foo","foo4":"foo"},{"Name":"def","Amount":5000,"Idnumber":"002","Date":"12/15/2017","Orders":[{"Order Number":"10","Date":"11/02/2017","Amount":7600,"Type":"trial"},{"Order Number":"16","Date":"05/31/2018","Amount":15000,"Type":"interim"}],"foo":"foo","foo2":"foo","foo3":"foo","foo4":"foo"}];
var result = data.reduce((r, {Orders, Idnumber})  => {
                   let orders = Orders.map(order => Object.assign({}, order, {Idnumber}));
                   return r.concat(orders);
                 },[]);
                 
console.log(result);
console.log('--------------Grouped By----------');
var groupedBy = result.reduce((r,o) => {
                  r[o.Type] = r[o.Type] || [];
                  r[o.Type].push(o)
                  return r;
                 },{});
console.log(groupedBy);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
newOrder = data.map(d => ({Orders: d.Orders, idNumber: d.Idnumber}))
```